# erro na leitura de JSON

Tags: java, json

possuo um código para ler Json, no meu ambiente de teste ele funciona 100%, porem quando eu altero para ler outro Json com outros paramentros ele acusa

```
Unexpected token COLON(:) at position 45.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at read.ReadJSONExample.main(ReadJSONExample.java:31)
```

aqui está o código, com o teste comentado

```
package read;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

import biblioteca.Atalho;
import conexao.StartUp;
import tradutor.Recognition;

public class ReadJSONExample {

    static Atalho atalho = new Atalho();
    static Recognition recognition = new Recognition();
    StartUp su = new StartUp();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("data.json")) {

            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

            JSONArray PersonList = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(PersonList);


            PersonList.forEach(per -> parsePersonObject((JSONObject) per));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//      if (isVariavelNull(atalho.getNome())) {
        if (isVariavelNull(recognition.getPredictedLabel())) {
            // -----codigo de comunicacao serial------------------------------------------------------
            // Modificar ("COMx") sendo x o valor da porta que o arduino esta
            // conectado
            SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
            sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

            if (sp.openPort()) {
                System.out.println("Porta aberta");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Porta nao aberta");
                return;
            }

            Thread.sleep(1500);
            for (Integer i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
                System.out.println("piscada: " + i);

                mandarSinalSerial(sp, 0);//high
                // manda o (0) para o serial
                // liga o led 1
//------pisca led
                mandarSinalSerial(sp, 2);//high
                mandarSinalSerial(sp, 3);//low
//------                
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            mandarSinalSerial(sp, 1);//low

            if (sp.closePort()) {
                System.out.println("Porta fechada");
            } else {
                System.out.println("porta não fechada");
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    private static void mandarSinalSerial(SerialPort sp, Integer comando) throws IOException {
        sp.getOutputStream().write(comando);
        sp.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static void parsePersonObject(JSONObject person) {
//      Atalho atalho = new Atalho();
        Recognition recognition = new Recognition();

        JSONObject PersonObject = (JSONObject) person.get("Person");

//      atalho.setNome((String) PersonObject.get("nome"));
        recognition.setPredictedLabel((String) PersonObject.get("StreamLabel"));

//      atalho.setSobrenome((String) PersonObject.get("sobrenome"));
        recognition.setConfidence((Double) PersonObject.get("Confidence"));

//      System.out.printf(atalho.getNome());
//      System.out.println(" "+atalho.getSobrenome());
        System.out.printf(recognition.getPredictedLabel());
        System.out.println(" " + recognition.getConfidence());
    }

    public static boolean isVariavelNull(String s) {
        return s == null;
    }

}
```

Json de teste

```
[{"Person":{"nome":"Aaaaa","sobrenome":"Bbbbb"}}]
```

Json que dá erro

```
{"stream_label":"INHVP1",
"people":[
"top_left":{"x":984,"y":422},
"recognition":{"predictedLabel":"Aaaaa Bbbbb",
"confidence":50.20001732681656},
"bottom_right":{"x":1117,"y":623}}]}
```

O erro está apontando que o Json está dando erro, como eu contorno esse erro? sendo que ele é gerado dessa maneira ?

Comment: Mas seu `JSON` está errado mesmo. No `array` `people` você está definindo propriedades quando deveria ser uma lista.

Comment: @Sorack como eu posso fazer uma alteração no meu código para interpreta-lo?

Comment: @JulioOtero você está recebendo de quem?

Comment: Se o JSON é inválido, eu acho que a API não vai conseguir ler. Tem que ver quem gerou esse JSON errado e arrumar lá, eu acho...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado estou recebendo de um software de reconhecimento Facial

Comment: @JulioOtero então, se ele gera esse dado de fato, ele não está gerando JSON propriamente dito. Você precisaria de um interpretador mais mole, reconhecendo um padrão distinto do JSON

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado entendi, alguma dica de como procurar isso na internet?

Comment: @JulioOtero nenhuma dica xD Talvez a documentação do software diga algo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado puts =/, se eu pegar um leitor de .txt eu consigo gravar as informações em uma variável para posteriormente utiliza-la?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"resolvi" o meu problema, ao invés de interpretar o json como json eu utilizei o split, pois um json "é" um txt... funcionou

a logica por trás é :

1. Identificou uma pessoa? quantos % ?
2. Se  identificou acende um led1
3. Se não identificou acende um led2

   ```
   package read;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;

   import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

   import tradutor.Pessoa;

   public class JoinSplit {

   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   try {
       BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.json"));
       String linha = "";
       String separador = "},";
       while (buffer.ready()) {
           linha = buffer.readLine();

           String[] dados = linha.split(separador);
           Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(dados[0]);

           if (buffer.readLine().contains("\"bottom_right\"")) {


               // ----------------------------------------------------------------

               if (isVariavelNull(Pessoa.getConfidence())) {
                   System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                   System.out.println(Pessoa.getConfidence());
                   System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                   SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
                   sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);
                   sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

                   if (sp.openPort()) {
                       System.out.println("Porta aberta");
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("Porta nao aberta");
                       return;
                   }

                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                   for (Integer i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
                       //liga led OK
                       mandarSinalSerial(sp, 0);
                       // ------
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                   }
                   // desliga led OK
                   mandarSinalSerial(sp, 1);


                   if (sp.closePort()) {
                       System.out.println("Porta fechada");
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("porta não fechada");
                   }
                   return;
               }
               // -----------------------------------------------------
           }
       } 

               System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
               System.out.println("pessoa nao cadastrada");
               System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
               SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
               sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);
               sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

               if (sp.openPort()) {
                   System.out.println("Porta aberta");
               } else {
                   System.out.println("Porta nao aberta");
                   return;
               }

               Thread.sleep(100);
               for (Integer i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
                   //liga led NOK
                   mandarSinalSerial(sp, 2);// high
                   // ------
                   Thread.sleep(500);
               }
               // desliga led NOK
               mandarSinalSerial(sp, 3);// low

               if (sp.closePort()) {
                   System.out.println("Porta fechada");
               } else {
                   System.out.println("porta não fechada");
               }
               return;

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }

   public static boolean isVariavelNull(String s) {
   return s != null;
   }

   private static void mandarSinalSerial(SerialPort sp, Integer comando) throws IOException {
       sp.getOutputStream().write(comando);
       sp.getOutputStream().flush();
   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Mas seu JSON está errado mesmo. No array people você está definindo propriedades quando deveria ser uma lista.

Você pode conferir que o `Javascript` não consegue interpretar seus dados com a sintaxe que foi definida abaixo:

```js
x = {"stream_label":"INHVP1",
"people":[
"top_left":{"x":984,"y":422},
"recognition":{"predictedLabel":"Aaaaa Bbbbb",
"confidence":50.20001732681656},
"bottom_right":{"x":1117,"y":623}}]};
```